# Giant Resistor vs Current divider

Tags: amplifier, resistors, microphone

1 GigaOhm resistors are so damn expensive.

(Don't ask, I'm trying to build a large diaphragm condenser microphone from scratch)

As an microphone pre-amplifier I am trying to bias a transistor and charge the capacitor plate at the same time similar to the setup in the Alice microphone circuit: 
[image]

While I could just use AC coupling in between the capsule and the transistor base, I want to try and minimize middle-man components but also achieve decent amplification with little noise. I was wondering if it was sane to substitute the single 1G resistor with a current divider setup.

P.S: If the answer is no, I will have to resort to using a Popsicle stick instead.

Answer (score 2):

It took me less than one minute to find this: http://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-Neohm/RGP0207CHK1G0/?qs=ip69W3eHERWnWvdTrALHzw==

Alternatively, you could use two 500M ohm in series.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your tolerance needs or other parameters it's really impossible to help you find a part.  I mean a toothpick or piece of paper could even be the answer depending on how accurate you want it to be.

Try searching Digikey or Mouser (like @RitchRock).  Here's some results from Digikey for through-hole parts: 
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/resistors/through-hole-resistors/53?k=resisors&k=&pkeyword=resisors&pv3=1&pv3=3&pv3=4&pv3=2&FV=ffe00035%2C4062a&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

The nice low tolerance ones are expensive for resistors but not ridiculous.